# Run a specific MySQL query based on what's selected in an HTML select box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

This question isn't really about what's wrong with some code.  It's about how to go about doing something.  This is why no code is posted.  Is there a way to run a specific MySQL query based on what's selected in an HTML select box?  Does a form have to be used here or is there another way?

I have now added the code and have tried using the switch statement way; however, the two textboxes are not being populated.  Any ideas?  The text in between the dashed lines isn't really in the code but just a placeholder for the purpose of the question.

```
<?php
---db login info here---

switch($_GET['string'])
{
    case "another string":
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE id = '1'");
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
       break;
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "document.getElementById('textbox').value = '$row[0]'";
echo "document.getElementById('textbox2').value = '$row[1]'";
echo "</script>";   
?>
```

Comment: try echoing in the case and vardumping of $row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. You can use forms or javascript URL call or ajax to perform this operation.

What you need to do it, based on the value selected in the selectbox, you need to run the sql statement in a switch case or if conditions.
The best option would be switch case for these kind of operations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to do this

1. put the MySQL in the value of each option *(VERY USEFUL WHEN YOU DON'T WANT YOUR DATABASE ANYMORE)* <-- **DON'T DO THIS ITS VERY UNSAFE**

   ```
   mysql_query($_GET["selectbox"]);
   ```
2. make a array with MySQL queries and put the key in the value of each option

   ```
   $mysqlqueryarr = array("SELECT banana FROM monkey","UPDATE monkey SET mouth='open'");
   mysql_query($mysqlqueryarr[$_GET["selectbox"]]);
   ```
3. make a switch what executes the queries

   ```
   switch($_GET['selectbox']){
   case 'monkey':
      mysql_query("SELECT monkey FROM zoo");
      break;
   case 'dog':
      mysql_query("SELECT dog FROM farm");
      break;
   }
   ```
4. make a superlong if(){ ... }else if(){ ... }else if(){etc. what looks for what there is in the selectbox and executes SQL

   ```
   if(isset($_GET['selectbox']) && $_GET['selectbox'] == "foood"){
        mysql_query("UPDATE wishlist SET needs = needs");
   } else if(isset($_GET['selectbox']) && $_GET['selectbox'] == "satisfied") {
        mysql_query("UPDATE wishlist SET needs = NULL");
   }
   ```

That's every way I know,

Comment: This is really vulnerable to threats like SQL Injection. Zero Security Method.

Comment: the first it is the rest isn't

Comment: In your switch example would "monkey" be one of the <option>s for the <select> tag?

Comment: I cannot get the linkage to work between the case and the corresponding selected option.  It works for the default case and the query result is correct.  So the textboxes won't populate based on the option selected for the non-default case.  Here is the pastebin link: pastebin.com/B74GAabv

Comment: @programm3r its not the IDthat decides what the name is in the get its the name attribute and never use spaces in the name or ID attributes

Comment: Are you saying that the argument of the $_GET is supposed to be the name of an <option> not the ID?

Comment: @programm3r yes so when you have `<input name="bleeder" id="bandage">` then you should use `$_GET['bleeder']`

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm trying to grab a select box using $_GET not a textbox. That is why I tried $_GET('select box id'), but that didn't work. I printed out $_GET('select box id'), and got nothing. Maybe $_GET can't be used outside of forms. Any ideas? Here is the code: pastebin.com/hH61EG0A